# Using autoResizingMask with CGRectZero

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, autoresizingmask

I am building a footer for a tableview's section. The height of the footer will be specified in `heightForFooterInSection`, so in `viewForFooterInSection` I would like to just add the subview and specify that the footer view should fill whatever footer height is specified (this footer size will be dynamic). So, I am using `CGRectZero` as the initial frame and telling the footer view to expand to fill its parent view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    footerView = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    footerView = [UIColor greenColor];
    return footerView;
}
```

This works as expected - the footer of the table view is filled completely with the green view.

But now I want to add a `UITextView` to the footer. The text view should fill the same space, but leave a 5-point border:

```
{
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    footerView = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    footerView = [UIColor greenColor];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(footerView.frame, 5, 5)];
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [footerView addSubview:textView];
    return footerView;
}
```

Instead of filling the footer view (with a 5 point margin), the text view does not appear at all. It likely has a frame of `CGRectZero` (or maybe even -5 x -5?). If I set the inset to 0, 0, however, it expands as expected.

What is the explanation for this? And If I can't use an inset of `CGRectZero` for the initial frame, what am I expected to use when the frame of the footerView can not be known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGRectInset will create a rectangle based on the existing rectangle.  It doesn't refer to the footer view ever again: only when it is calculating it this one time.  In this case, since you are trying to inset a rectangle with a zero size, this applies from the docs:

> **Discussion**. 
>   The rectangle is standardized and then the inset parameters are
>   applied. If the resulting rectangle would have a negative height or
>   width, a null rectangle is returned.

Therefore, you are creating your label with a null rectangle.

I would create the footer with a "typical" size, then an appropriately sized label with the autoResizingMask that you want, and **then** set your footerView to zero if that is what you want it set to.

Comment: Your last sentence is the correct answer, except you don't need to set the frame to zero. The footer is resized to the appropriate size by the table view, so if you need margins, layout etc., an arbitrary size is the way to go.

Comment: @jrturton: True, but he seems to want it at zero for some reason and there would be no harm in doing so.

Comment: Thanks. Yes there's no requirement to set it back to zero, I was only using it in absence of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the TextView creates the content in the background, so at the moment of initialization it's empty. I usualy end up using `[string sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]`

```
CGSize size = [aString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320,500) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
```