# Can any one please explain what is use of CGRectZero

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I am new to iOS. Can any one please explain what the use is of `CGRectZero` and where it is used?

Comment: This is an example of how it can be used :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905144/using-autoresizingmask-with-cgrectzero

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CGRectZero equals to CGRectMake(0,0,0,0). Usually it's used to fast-initialize CGRect object.

For example:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
frame.size.width = someWidth;
frame.size.height = someHeight;
myView.frame = frame;
```

From Apple's doc:

```
/* The "zero" rectangle -- equivalent to CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0). */ 

CG_EXTERN const CGRect CGRectZero
  CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

Comment: Typo in your answer, CFRectZero should be CGRectZero.

Comment: @Wayne nice catch :)

Answer (score 2):

```
CGRectZero = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

**CGRectZero**

A rectangle constant with location (0,0), and width and height of 0. The zero rectangle is equivalent to CGRectMake(0,0,0,0).

Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

Declared in CGGeometry.h.

more details [Geometric Zeros](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPointZero)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `CGRectZero` is to create and initialize a CGRect at (0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0 -**

> A rectangle constant with location (0,0), and width and height of 0.
>   The zero rectangle is equivalent to CGRectMake(0,0,0,0).

```
CGRect.zero  == CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
```

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrectzero)