# Row number in UITableViewController does not conform the protocol function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use a dynamic `tableViewController`. I implement the `numberOfSection` to return 4, and the `numberOfRowInSection` return 1. These are the only changes I made for the blank `TableViewController`. But when I run it on simulator, it shows multiple cells, which I expected to be only four cells. Why is that?

Note: If I change the height of each cell to let the screen only fit four cells at a time, it will work fine since it won't let be me scroll down. So I guess is the `tableViewController` always try to fill the screen no matter how many cell it should display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `UITableView` will always continue to fill the screen with 'empty' cells of the default row height. To prevent this, you could add the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

(For Swift, check @VictorSigler's answer.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer and it works! One more question: CGRectZero is just like CGRect(0,0,0,0), How the whole footerView place be covered with a "nothing" CGRect?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it just overrides the default footer.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the editing of my question !

Comment: @ZhehaoVictorZhou You're welcome you can see more about `CGRectZero` in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217964/can-any-one-please-explain-what-is-use-of-cgrectzero

Comment: Thanks! however that actually make me more confused about why a "nothing" CGRect can cover the tableFootView.